# subscription succed, but but callback function does not display data

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I wrote code to publish and subscribe to topics. The publication works very well. The subscription also, but my **on_message** callback function does not display data (print("**message.payload**")) although I can see the data in protobuf format on node-red.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from google.protobuf.struct_pb2 import Struct
import json
import pub_message_pb2 as pub_message
from google.protobuf.json_format import Parse

    MQTT_HOST = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    CLIENT_ID =  "centos"
    BROKER_PORT = 1883
    CA_CERT = "caCert.pem"
    CERTFILE = "ServerCert.pem"
    KEYFILE = "ServerKey.pem"
    MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL = 45
    
    publish_topic = "user/7/device/8CF9572000023509/downlink"
    subscribe_topic = "user/7/device/8CF9572000023509/uplink"
    token = ""
    
    payload = Parse(json.dumps({
            "Token":"OVc0/opKynDuz/DxVzaUcA==",
            "Params":{
                "FPort":8,
                "Data":"BAoAAQ==",
                "Confirm":False,
                "DevEUI":"8CF9572000023509" 
            }
        }),pub_message.DeviceDownlink())
    
    def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
        print("Published...")
    
    def on_connect(client,userdata,flags,rc):
        client.subscribe(subscribe_topic,1)
        client.publish(publish_topic,payload.SerializeToString())
        
    
    def on_message(client,userdata,message):
        print(message.topic)
        print(message.payload)
        #client.disconnect()
    
    client = mqtt.Client(CLIENT_ID,clean_session=False,userdata=None,protocol=mqtt.MQTTv31,transport="tcp")

    client.message_callback_add(subscribe_topic,on_message)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_publish = on_publish
    client.on_message = on_message
    
    client.tls_set(ca_certs=CA_CERT,certfile=CERTFILE,keyfile=KEYFILE)
    
    client.username_pw_set(username="xxxxxx",password="xxxxxx")
    
    client.connect(MQTT_HOST,BROKER_PORT,MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL)
    
    client.loop_forever()
```

is there something that is not done well? Your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Try moving all the setting of the callbacks to before the call to `connect()`

Comment: I moved the callbacks as you suggested but the data is not always displayed.

Comment: "is not always displayed" - please clarify what you mean by that (e.g. messages come through for a while then stop, messages are skipped seemingly randomly etc). Probably best to update your question with full details.

Comment: it means that print ("message.topic") and print ("message.payload") in on_message callback do not display anything although I can see the data in protobuf format on node-red.

Comment: OK - so is `on_message` now being called? Please update your code to reflect the changes made following comment from @hardillb. It would also be useful if you could subscribe with a utility (e.g. [mosquitto_sub](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html)) and detail the full command line and results (confirms the issue is with your code rather than broker configuration and enables us to see topics etc).

Comment: it works now. the subscription topic was not the right one